# git can't checkout branch for the first time without the remote name

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have cloned a repo and added my fork as another remote but I cannot check out a branch for the first time (in this case `master`, which is not their default branch) without specifying which remote.

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/zstd.git
cd zstd
git remote add jay https://github.com/jay/zstd.git
git fetch jay
git checkout master

error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

If I specify the remote it works:

```
git checkout -b master origin/master

Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'master'
```

I'm curious why I need to specify the remote in this case. I must be remembering this wrong but I'm pretty sure that wasn't always necessary. This is true of any branch that's in both repos, for example, `git checkout zstd_help` would also fail the first time unless I explicitly specified origin remote.

Git version: `git version 2.7.4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is the second remote you've added. If you just clone the repo and immediately try to checkout `master`, it will work:

```
mureinik@computer ~/src/git
$ git clone https://github.com/facebook/zstd.git
Cloning into 'zstd'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 9, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
remote: Total 43954 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 43945
Receiving objects: 100% (43954/43954), 23.29 MiB | 682.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (32256/32256), done.

mureinik@computer ~/src/git
$ cd zstd

mureinik@computer ~/src/git/zstd (dev)
$ git checkout master
Switched to a new branch 'master'
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
```

once you add `jay`, the remote branch name `master` becomes ambiguous (it could refer to `origin/master` or `jay/master`), and thus when you try to check it out it fails.

I'm not sure when exactly this happened, but newer versions of git (I'm using 2.28) will give a clearer error message in this situation:

```
# After adding the second "jay" remote

mureinik@computer ~/src/git/zstd (master)
$ git checkout verbose
hint: If you meant to check out a remote tracking branch on, e.g. 'origin',
hint: you can do so by fully qualifying the name with the --track option:
hint:
hint:     git checkout --track origin/<name>
hint:
hint: If you'd like to always have checkouts of an ambiguous <name> prefer
hint: one remote, e.g. the 'origin' remote, consider setting
hint: checkout.defaultRemote=origin in your config.
fatal: 'verbose' matched multiple (2) remote tracking branches
```

Comment: Thanks. I did some more testing and the version of git I have seems to allow some repos with two remotes and ambiguous branch names to check out those branches for the first time without specifying the remote, but does not allow it for others like the example I asked about.